# Send option from select_tag to the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a helper with an array of Organizations:

```
def pros
  pros = ['ASCAP', 'BMI', 'SESAC']
end
```

My form:

```
<%= f.label :pro, "Performing Rights Organization" %>
<%= select_tag(:pro, options_for_select(pros)) %>
```

My Songs controller with :pro included in list of permitted params:

```
def song_params
  params.require(:song).permit(:artist, :song_name, :writer_first_name, :writer_last_name, :cleared, :pro)
end
```

Server Log:

```
    Started POST "/songs" for ::1 at 2016-06-27 21:39:06 -0400
Processing by SongsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"L70xGWxlf+eeQc2hbP/hywKdy4+TBsaKgVP7sP5edG4TSnC6Jf3wFyBjZn9/nANnoKnm6NGj0Hw6DyjsyJazug==", "song"=>{"artist"=>"The High Fives", "song_name"=>"Off Track", "writer_first_name"=>"Josh", "writer_last_name"=>"Zandman", "cleared"=>"1"}, "pro"=>"ASCAP", "commit"=>"Create Song"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "songs" ("artist", "song_name", "writer_first_name", "writer_last_name", "cleared", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["artist", "The High Fives"], ["song_name", "Off Track"], ["writer_first_name", "Josh"], ["writer_last_name", "Zandman"], ["cleared", true], ["created_at", 2016-06-28 01:39:06 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-06-28 01:39:06 UTC], ["user_id", 1]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
  Song Store (17.6ms)  {"id":2}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/songs/2
Completed 302 Found in 47ms (Searchkick: 17.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)


Started GET "/songs/2" for ::1 at 2016-06-27 21:39:06 -0400
Processing by SongsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Song Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering songs/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered songs/_song.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered songs/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 277ms (Views: 275.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

I can successfully assign an Organization to :pro column in Rails Console, but when I try and add it from the form, it doesn't save into the database.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. Can you look in either your logfile (eg `log/development.log`) or the output in the window in which you started your server and check the output to see what params are actually coming through to you. If there is something stopping your params from being permitted, you will also get another line telling you which params were not permitted. Edit your question and add all of that to your original question (don't put it here in comments because code-formatting in comments is dreadful) :)

Comment: Also show us your controller action and what you have in the permit/require method in your controller. :) Otherwise we're just guessing at what your problem is and may guess wrong.

Comment: @TarynEast I update the question - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be with your pro parameter not being permitted in your *params* hash. You can check in the web server console if the parameter was filtered out when you submitted the form.

Assuming you have something like the following in your controller:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
    # Some public methods [...]
    private
    # Some private methods [...]

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def organization_params
        params.require(:organization)
            .permit(:param1, :param2)
    end
end
```

You can allow the *pro* parameter by adding it to the list of permitted parameters in the *params* hash:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
    # Some public methods [...]
    private
    # Some private methods [...]

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def organization_params
        params.require(:organization)
            .permit(:param1, :param2, :pro)  # <= add your pro parameter here
    end
end
```

Since the parameter is allowed in the *params* hash, it will be passed to the Organization model and will be persisted to the database.

EDIT: It looks like your pro parameter is outside the scope of song and therefore it is not being passed to the Song object through *params[:song]*.

I'd suggest changing your select_tag to:

```
select("song", "pro", options_for_select(pros))
```

The *select_tag* was not scoping the *pro* parameter value inside song, so it were basically generating:

```
<select name="pro">
```

In order for it to actually pass the *pro* parameter to *params[:song]* it needs to generate:

```
<select name="sond[pro]">
```

Since *select_tag* was not passing *pro* to *params[:song]*, instantiating a Song object with *params[:song]* would not include the *pro* parameter.

Comment: Hi, I do have it included in my list of params.

Comment: Could you please follow the instructions (to provide more info) provided in your original post by Taryn East? This way, we'll be able to see more precisely where your problem might be and help you further :)

Comment: Doing what you suggested in your edit, worked! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :) Editted the original post with the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I know you have the solution, but for future reference to debug this kind of problem, you should always look at this line in your output:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"L70xGWxlf+eeQc2hbP/hywKdy4+TBsaKgVP7sP5edG4TSnC6Jf3wFyBjZn9/nANnoKnm6NGj0Hw6DyjsyJazug==",
"song"=>{"artist"=>"The High Fives", "song_name"=>"Off Track", "writer_first_name"=>"Josh", "writer_last_name"=>"Zandman", "cleared"=>"1"},
"pro"=>"ASCAP", "commit"=>"Create Song"}
```

You can clearly see the parameters that you need the `"pro" => "ASCAP"` to be inside the part that is the `"song" =>` section. and use the above solution to solve it...
Checking the output in your server logs is a great way to figure out what's causing a bug :)

Comment: Thanks for the help Taryn! I really appreciate it